# Opening a resource file in a servlet on Openshift

Tags: java, tomcat, servlets, deployment, openshift

I'm in troubles with opening file within my web-app. I tried it locally within Eclipse and it works fine but when I try to deploy it on Tomcat 6 on Openshift it doesn't find resource files for my web-app. There are some txt files in a `ProjectFiles` directory stored in `WEB-INF` directory; the code that locally opens file is

```
String nome_file = "C\:\\Users\\miKKo\\workspace\\fantacalcio_project\\WebContent\\WEB-INF\\ProjectFiles\\Risultati\\risultati_" + nome_lega + ".txt"; 

BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(nome_file));
```

I've pushed them within Git in the same repository (on server I renamed my project in "ROOT") and I've substituted string with this

```
String nome_file = this.getServletConfig().getServletContext().getContextPath()+"/WebContent/WEB-INF/ProjectFiles/Risultati/risultati_" + nome_lega + ".txt";
```

but it doesn't work. I've also tried with a context attribute

```
/var/lib/openshift/51c6178a5004467630000019/jbossews/work/Catalina/localhost/_/WEB-INF/ProjectFiles
```

but the thrown exception is always

> java.io.FileNotFoundException: (#path) (No such file or directory)

What can I do for this?

Comment: I've also tried with System.getenv("$OPENSHIFT_REPO_DIR") and System.getenv("$OPENSHIFT_DATA_DIR") used in servlet and JSP pages but both of them return a null string. I don't know why

Answer (score 2):

Say your file is in the following location:

```
/WEB-INF/ProjectFiles/Risultati/risultat_text_file.txt
```

Then using:

```
String path = "/WEB-INF/ProjectFiles/Risultati/risultat_text_file.txt";
InputStream inputStream =  new FileInputStream(this.getServletConfig().getServletContext().getRealPath(path));
```

Should work for you. Note that, [ServletContext.getRealPath()](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletContext.html#getRealPath%28java.lang.String%29) return the real OS path corresponding to the given virtual path.

***Edit:***

If this doesn't work for your case, you really need to revisit your virtual path. You can manually check that does this file exist in the expected directory in the war file or you can log the output of the `getRealPath()` method to examine what's really going on! If necessary you can put `"/"` in your `getRealPath()` method and examine what is your application's root path.

Comment: it doesn't work, i've tried in this way

String path="/WEB-INF/ProjectFiles/Risultati/risultati_test.txt";

InputStream inputStream =  new FileInputStream(this.getServletConfig().getServletContext().getRealPath(path));

BufferedInputStream reader = new BufferedInputStream(inputStream);

Besides, i need to read file and use methods like readLine() of BufferedReader class, and BufferedInputStream hasn't them.

Comment: Did you logged the path returned by the getRealPath() method? What do you see?

Comment: The inputStream object returned by getRealPath() and converted to string is java.io.FileInputStream@60af0b

Sorry if I don't understand this thing

Comment: Just print output of the bellow code: `this.getServletConfig().getServletContext().getRealPath(path)`

Comment: However, yesterday i resolved another problem with a properties file in this case

Properties properties = new Properties();
InputStream prop_link=getServletContext().getResourceAsStream("/WEB-INF/fantacalcio.properties");
properties.load(prop_link);

but for this files I don't succeed

Comment: OK, What might cause problem to this file? Did you logged the value, in the suggested way?

Comment: The value of getRealPath() on server is "null"!

Comment: Hmm, that means. your sevlet container cannot translate the path "/WEB-INF/ProjectFiles/Risultati/risultati_test.txt". Did you re-examined the file exits in `/WEB-INF/ProjectFiles/Risultati/risultati_test.txt` path after the deployment?

Comment: Yes, it exists. However, the opening of fantacalcio.properties file, that is also located in /WEB-INF, works correctly (it is used for database parameters)

Comment: this.getServletConfig().getServletContext().getRealPath("/") returns "null"

Maybe there are restrictions on Openshift about the access to path. I read that I should use System.getenv("$OPENSHIFT_REPO_DIR") and System.getenv("$OPENSHIFT_DATA_DIR") to obtain paths. However, thank you for supporting me!

Answer (score 2):

Since I don't get application's root realpath, I resolved in this way:

```
String path="/WEB-INF/ProjectFiles/Risultati/risultati_test.txt";
InputStream inputStream = this.getServletConfig().getServletContext().getResourceAsStream(path);
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));
```

and now it works. By the way, I also found useful informations here

[getResourceAsStream() vs FileInputStream](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2308188/getresourceasstream-vs-fileinputstream)

Comment: `this.getServletConfig().getServletContext()` can be simplified to `this.getServletContext()`